# Run bash script when Stack Created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm designing an AWS stack that contains multiple instances that run a handful of services comprised of a few tasks each. One of these services uses NFS to store configuration, and this configuration needs to be setup ONCE when the stack is created.

I've come up with a way to run a configuration script ONCE when the stack is created:

1. Configure the service that needs to configure itself to run a single task
2. When the task starts, check if the configuration exists. If it doesn't, run a configuration script and then update the desired task count so that other instances are created

(1) is necessary to avoid a race condition.

Although this works well, it strikes me as a very round-about way to achieve something simple: run a bash script ONCE when my stack is created. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: By 'task' and 'service' are you referring to ECS, or something else entirely? Some code examples would help to clarify your description of your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a one-off Bash script using an [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) resource with an [`InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-instanceinitiatedshutdownbehavior) property of `terminate` (to terminate the instance after the script executes), and a [`DependsOn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute set to the last-created resource in your stack (so the EC2 instance gets created and the Bash script gets executed at the end):

```
Description: Run a bash script once when a stack is created.
Mappings:
  # amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20161221-x86_64-gp2
  RegionMap:
    us-east-1:
      "64": "ami-9be6f38c"
Resources:
  MyResource:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  WebServer:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: MyResource
    Properties:
      ImageId: !FindInMap [ RegionMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", 64]
      InstanceType: m3.medium
      InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: terminate
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            # [Contents of bash script here...]
            shutdown -h now
```